# How to add content tags in all articles (Joomla)

Tags: joomla, tags

I have found a great plugin that sets Facebook comments on an article where you write down  {fcomment}.

The problem with this is that you have to manually put this in each article, what is time consuming work.

Is there a method to put specific content in header / footer (in this case {fcomment) that display Facebook comments) of each article?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ReReplacer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/replace/4336) and then match some part of the article html and add your custom tag, like:

```
Match: <span class="article_separator">&nbsp;</span>

Change to: {fcomment}<span class="article_separator">&nbsp;</span>
```

Comment: Thanks it's what I looked after :)